# R break up data frame into list using vector of number of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` that I want to break up into a list of `data.frame`s using a vector that will tell me how many rows should be in each consecutive list element.

Sample Data

```
vectornom <- c(1,2,4,3)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20)
```

Desired result

```
> new_list
[[1]]
  x  y
  1 11
[[2]]
  x   y
  2  12
  3  13
[[3]]
  x   y
  4  14
  5  15
  6  16
  7  17
[[4]]
  x   y
  8  18
  9  19
  10 20
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: `split(df, rep(1:length(vectornom), vectornom))`

Comment: beautifully done, worthy of posting as an answer.

Comment: @RichAtMango Thanks, I'm pairing your answer to my previous question with this one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the (pretty awesome) `split` function for this, using `vectornom` to create the index on which to "split"

```
split(df, rep(1:length(vectornom), vectornom))
```